# .NET is there a trace or diagnostic setting to show when new threads are created and destroyed?

Tags: c#, multithreading, crash-dumps

We have a C# Console App which occasionally hangs with no obvious error.  I have taken a Crash Dump a few times, and opened the DMP file in Visual Studio to see what is going on in the app.  As far as I can see, there are no deadlocks (opening it with Windbg shows nothing locked also).  It appears like the app keeps spawning new threads until it runs out of resources. (?)

It's not clear where in the app it is creating all these threads, and also why the threads aren't being destroyed normally.  Below is screenshot of what I see in Threads view of Visual Studio (from the dump file).  None of the Threads shows a Call stack which is in any code of the application.

Is there any way to turn on .NET tracing to log whenever a new thread is created and destroyed?

[image: Threads View from Visual Studio]

Comment: I would begin to check all places where System.Threading.Thread is used or Task.Run or TaskFactory.StartNew methods are used, have you did this? I belive the threads are not destroyed because they have an reference to an object still in use so they can't be cleaned by the GC.

Comment: You'll have to select the managed debugging engine to get to see the managed stack trace of these threads.

Comment: @HansPassant:  thanks Hans - I was choosing the Mixed debugging engine.  I definitely more threads with a Location.  However, still many threads say Location <not available>.  If it says <not available>, does it mean thread has completed but not yet Garbage Collected?  Maybe app is creating threads faster than they can be cleaned up?  (As opposed to the threads being blocked waiting on a lock?)

Comment: @user743414: maybe you're right - I think these threads are invoking an instance delegate which is wrapped around a method of another object.  So perhaps that delegate reference is considered a live object, and preventing GC?

Comment: I don't think hang dump analysis is trivial, so if possible, open a support case via http://support.microsoft.com for assistance. Besides, do capture multiple hang dumps when the app hangs, with some time interval. Then when you analyze the threads, you gain more insights on what the threads did within the interval. A single dump might be useless, unless it shows a typical cause such as deadlock.